# Hooke's law and modulus of elasticity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, string, elasticity, stress-strain

I'm having trouble in understanding the following question which state modulus of elasticity in Newton.
Is it possible that we can define modulus of elasticity in Newton somehow??
I am getting a wrong answer as I used the values of modulus of elasticity in newton to solve the question.
Please help me with this question

[image: the following is a picture of question]

Comment: The modulus of elasticity has units of N/m$^2$ not N.

Answer (score 1):

They use "modulus of elasticity" which is not the same as "spring constant".
The spring constant is in N/m and is the quantity most used in physics.
But for a given type of spring (material, geometry) the spring constant depends on the length of the spring. It is actually inverse proprtional to the length. The "modulus of elasticity" is constant for a given type of spring, no matter what length you cut it to. It is used by spring manufacturers usually. To get the spring constant of a given spring you divide this constant (in N) by the spring length. So, a longer spring has a lower k, it is less stiff than a short one, of the same type.
This "modulus of elasticity" is not the same as Young's modulus which is a material property and has units of pascal (like pressure).

Comment: Should I divide by natural length like this:       spring constant= 16/0.8= 20 and      second spring constant= 36/1.2   ??

Comment: But then I can find the extension by Hooks law : F = KX where force should be 20 N and k is what I have found but how we can we write in h then as first part says??

Comment: If you know the total distance CD (3 m) and the distance QD (h) what will be the lengt of each spring in this state? Then, as you know the relaxed length of each spring, what will be the extension or compression of each spring?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the usual way to deal with the notion of modulus of elasticity. But by the context, it is clear that the relevant equation is: $$F = E\frac{\Delta h}{h}$$ In that way, $E$ has units of force.